# Mobile Emulator Connection Failure (Merge Replication)

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I am attempting to replicate a SQL CE 3.5 SP1 database but upon syncrhonization, I am thrown the following error:

"Failure to connect to SQL Server with provided connection information. SQL Server does not exist, access is denied because the IIS user is not a valid user on the computer running SQL Server, or the password is incorrect."

I am using the Windows Mobile 6 Professional emulator and the machine I am attempting to connect to is a Windows Virtual Machine running Windows XP Professional SP3. I have configured the network adapter settings for the emulator (I can access web pages), verified user permissions, double checked IIS settings, and triple checked my connection string:

```
            SqlCeReplication rpl = null;

        try
        {
            // Creates the replication object.
            rpl = new SqlCeReplication();
            // Establishes the connection string.
            rpl.SubscriberConnectionString = @"Data Source = \Program Files\ParkSurvey\ParkSurvey.sdf; Password = *; Temp File Max Size = 512; 
            Max Database Size = 512; Max Buffer Size = 512; Flush Interval = 20; Autoshrink Threshold = 10; Default Lock Escalation = 100";
            // Sets the Publisher properties.
            rpl.PublisherSecurityMode = SecurityType.NTAuthentication;
            rpl.Publisher = "PUBLISHER";
            rpl.PublisherLogin = "INDICOPUBLIC\\subuser";
            rpl.PublisherPassword = "*";
            rpl.PublisherDatabase = "PUBLISHER";
            rpl.Publication = "ParkSurveyPublication";
            // Sets the internet replication properties.
            rpl.InternetUrl = "http://replication/sqlce/sqlcesa35.dll";
            rpl.InternetLogin = "INDICOPUBLIC\\subuser";
            rpl.InternetPassword = "*";
            rpl.ConnectionManager = true;
            // Sets the Distributor properties.
            rpl.Distributor = "PUBLISHER";
            rpl.DistributorLogin = "INDICOPUBLIC\\subuser";
            rpl.DistributorPassword = "psrAdmin";
            rpl.DistributorSecurityMode = SecurityType.NTAuthentication;
            // Sets the timeout properties.
            rpl.ConnectionRetryTimeout = 120;
            rpl.ConnectTimeout = 6000;
            rpl.ReceiveTimeout = 6000;
            rpl.SendTimeout = 6000;
            // Sets the Subscriber properties.
            rpl.Subscriber = "ParkSurveySubscriber";
            rpl.HostName = "Mobile1";
            rpl.CompressionLevel = 6;
            rpl.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.BiDirectional;
            // Call the replication methods.
            rpl.Synchronize();

        }
        catch (SqlCeException sqlEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sqlEx.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Disposing the replication object
            if (rpl != null)
            {
                rpl.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

I have also attempted to open the host machine itself in File Explorer on the mobile emulator and am prompted that "The network path was not found.". This leads me to believe it is ActiveSync issue within the emulator itself. Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try with IP adresse instead of hostname, and test the agent URL from IE on the device. Make sure to use the latest build of 3.5 SP2 on all components if your DB server is SQL 2012

Comment: I have also tried connecting to the IP address to no avail, and I am actually already using 3.5 SP2. The information I originally posted was a typo, my mistake. I have also troubleshooted whether it is a Virtual PC issue and tried to connect to my own PC, and other PCs on our network but had no luck.